# Basic trignometry - When finding the length of opposite side of triangle how to find the sine of an angle without a calculator?

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to find the length of opposite side in this triangle. I only know the angle and length of Hypotenuse.

[image: My triangle]

I know that we need *sin* and i can easily do it in a calculator, but is it possible to find a ***sin* angle** without a calculator?

Comment: Would be helpful if you draw a rough figure in the question

Comment: For some angles you can do this, possibly involving radicals, but for most the best you can do is an approximation (e.g. using the CORDIC algorithm) and there a calculator or computer or tables help

Comment: You see i can easily use a calculator but i want to not use one.

Comment: If the angle were 66° you could calculate the sine in terms of square roots, using some tedious algebra. But it gets *much* harder for general angles.

Comment: If you have a protractor, a compass and a ruler you can find values of sine or cosine without a calculator.

Comment: Another option is to use the addition formula to write this in terms of the sine and cosine of a small angle like $5.5^\circ$, and then use series expansions up to a few terms to hand-approximate those.